# How to create Generic Response handler for error and validate response using retrofit,rxjava and dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, rx-java2

I'm trying to create generic architecture to consume complex json structure as follows:

> **Json** Format

```
{
"type": "success",
"code": "s-groups-0006",
"description": "Index List successfully",
"result": {
    "asOnDate": 1505457095278,
    "indexList": [
        {
            "change": "22.35",
            "changePercent": "0.27",
            "isDefault": true,
            "isEditable": false
        }
    ]
}
```

}

> **Dagger** Format

```
@Singleton
fun provideGson(): Gson =
        GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
             //   .registerTypeAdapter(BaseResponse::class.java, RestDeserializer<BaseResponse<T>>())
                .create()
```

> **Rest** Deseralizers

```
 class RestDeserializer<T> : JsonDeserializer<T> {
@Throws(JsonParseException::class)
override fun deserialize(je: JsonElement, type: Type, jdc: JsonDeserializationContext): T? {
    val content = je.asJsonObject

    // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
    // to this deserializer
    return Gson().fromJson<T>(content, type)

}
```

}

> **Error callback**

```
abstract class ErrorCallBack<T : BaseResponse<T>> : DisposableObserver<T>() {

protected abstract fun onSuccess(t: T)

override fun onNext(t: T) {
    //You can return StatusCodes of different cases from your API and handle it here. I usually include these cases on BaseResponse and iherit it from every Response
    onSuccess(t)
}

override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

    when (e) {
        is HttpException -> {
            val responseBody = (e).response().errorBody()
            responseBody?.let {
                L.e("Error in call htttp exception")
            }
        }
        is SocketTimeoutException -> {
            // todo
            L.e("Error in Socket time out")
        }
        is IOException -> {
            // todo
            L.e("Error in IO Exception")
        }
        else -> {
            e.message?.let {
                // todo
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onComplete() {

}

private fun getErrorMessage(responseBody: ResponseBody): String {
    return try {
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(responseBody.string())
        jsonObject.getString("message")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message!!
    }

}
```

}

> **Repository**

```
    override fun getValidateUser(validateUser: ValidateUser): LiveData<ValidateUserResponse> {

    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ValidateUserResponse>()
    remoteServices.requestValidateUser(validateUser)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : ErrorCallBack<BaseResponse<ValidateUserResponse>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: BaseResponse<ValidateUserResponse>) {
                    if (t.type == CommonContents.SUCCESS) {
                        L.d("Success in validate user")
                        mutableLiveData.value = transform(t)
                    } else {
                        L.e("Validate User Error")
                    }
                }
            })
    return mutableLiveData
}
```

> **Data** Class

```
data class BaseResponse<out T>(
    @SerializedName(CommonContents.TYPE) val type: String,
    @SerializedName(CommonContents.CODE) val Code: String,
    @SerializedName(CommonContents.DESCRIPTION) val Description: String,
    @SerializedName(CommonContents.RESULT)val result: T? = null)
```

These are my structures and I try to make a generic structure but am facing an issue when invoking the Error callback.

**Please guide me how to achieve this. Can i call generic method inside generic Response?**

```
  .subscribeWith(object : ErrorCallBack<BaseResponse<ValidateUserResponse>>() {
```

Answer (score -1):

**Guide To Achieving Working Code**

This is my guide to making some code work. It is based on the principles of [Test Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

1. Set up your unit test environment in your IDE. Personally, I have been using JUnit 4 with Eclipse, but you may prefer JUnit 5 with JetBrains' IDE.
2. Write a unit test for your `ErrorCallback` class constructor. Make it pass. Next, write unit tests for each of the methods, to see that it behaves the way that you expect.
3. Write unit tests where your test fixture is a `PublishSubject<BaseResponse<Integer>>` for some number of different cases: normal data, sequence of normal data, normal data followed by error, normal data followed by completion.
4. From there, add some more tests so that you can test the entire observable chain.